# Remove Rows in excel where duplicates are present

Tags: excel, database, excel-formula, excel-2010

Suppose I have an excel sheet with 3 columns as Name, Age and Number. Names are A,B and C. Ages are 10,11 and 12. And Number are 5,7 and 5. In Number column, there is a duplicate value 5 in the third row which is already present in the first row. I need a method to remove the row where a duplicate value is present. Just keep the first row in case of duplicate values. That means a way to remove C's entry keeping A's entry.

This is just a small scenario I need to do this with way large data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard ribbon button in Excel in the "Data" tab called "Remove duplicates". This should do exactly what you want: https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/remove-duplicates.html

Comment: Remove duplicates will not solve this problem. I have stated that the number column has duplicate value but I want to remove the whole row where there's a duplicate value in either of the columns. Remove duplicate will not work here becaue the entire row is not duplicate.

Comment: So you only want to remove the row if the entire row is a duplicate? In that case I would create an extra column wherein you concatenate the values from the other rows and remove the duplicates from that row.

Answer (score 0):

Jaskunwar , looks like you did not give it a try else you could have found n number of solution as the problem looks very simple. If your question is something else please describe.

As Alex Suggested Remove Duplicate will solve your problem. You can use Conditional formatting, Pivot, If formula to achieve this.

Comment: Remove duplicates will not solve this problem. I have stated that the number column has duplicate value but I want to remove the whole row where there's a duplicate value in either of the columns. Remove duplicate will not work here becaue the entire row is not duplicate

Comment: in that case apply conditional formatting in each column to highlight duplicate values and delete...

Comment: Please upload one photo with the raw data and one with the desirable output .

Answer (score 0):

What about this? (select the range you need)

```
    Sub SpotUniques()

    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Select range", xTitleId, WorkRng.address, Type:=8)
    WorkRng.Select

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each cell In WorkRng 
    .Item(cell.Value) = .Item(cell.Value) + 1
    If .Item(cell.Value) = 1 Then
    With cell.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)
    End With
    End If
    Next cell
    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, Times As Long, i As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim str As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find the last row of column A
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        'Start Loop from the lastrow to row 1 upside down
        For i = Lastrow To 2 Step -1
            'Give value to str
            str = .Range("C" & i).Value
            'Set the range you want to search
            Set rng = .Range("C2:C" & Lastrow)
            'Count how many times str appears in rng
            Times = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, str)
            'If it is appears more than one time and A & i value equal to C
            If Times > 1 And .Range("A" & i).Value = "C" Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```